# Is it possible to render handlebars templates from a database on node.js?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, liquid, express-handlebars

I'm looking to create a single node.js application that will render multiple different client websites.

We currently run one node.js application per client website, but I think this might be overkill as the serverside logic is exactly the same for all of them, the only difference being the handlebars template.

I'm looking to re-architecture to have a single node.js application which will then render the different client's websites based on some incoming information, will use nginx to add a header or something to the request so the app knows which website to render.

Is it possible to store the handlebars template within a database and then request the template at render time? Rendering a simple single page should be easy enough, but I'm struggling to understand how partials would be rendered?

Looking to achieve something similar to Shopify's Storefront Renderer, not sure if it's possible to do with handlebars or if it's better to use of of the LiquidJs ports for Node to achieve this?

https://shopify.engineering/how-shopify-reduced-storefront-response-times-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I do this with different countries, same concept as you with different Clients.

You just create the Handlebars layout and put it in your partials folder. No need to put template in your database.

Then your server logic will have eg clientName, and your Handlebars will have IfEqual tags (you'll need an IfEqual helper)

Example:

Server route will give a variable clientName.

Handlebars you have the main view page with only the IfEqual helpers.

```
{{#ifEqual clientName 'Client Name 1'}}
  {{> client/clientName1}}
{{/ifEqual}}  
{{#ifEqual clientName 'Client Name 2'}}
  {{> client/clientName2}}
{{/ifEqual}}
```

Your helper function will be

```
    , helpers: {
    ifEqual: function(x, y, options) {
        return(x == y) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this)
    } // {{#ifEqual statusLogin 'unconfirmed'}} {{/ifEqual}}
```

Search nodejs handlebar helper if you dont know how to set it.

So my partial folder, you can create a folder in it called client, and put all your Handlebars template in there. Search for nodejs handlebars partial folder setup if you dont know how to do it.

The handlebar helper function I found it I think in stack overflow, so you can search for others if you want, but for me it works.

Your partial template files just do as normal Handlebar files.

So the main idea is User loads the page, depending on what Client flag you put it, it loads up that template.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it isn't scalable, you'll need to edit the template for each client you add, if it's a true saas with 100s or 1000s of clients this approach won't work

Comment: @Tam2 How wont it work? The code is already created. It's just database call to get the variables, which is quick. If you're worried about manually creating the partials for each client, you create a function that adds each client with it's template. Then you use fs to write the partials to the handlebars template.

Comment: @NhonHa That approach will work if you have very static templates. If you have a scaled up solution, you will probably want to offer the admins editing capabilities. Storing the templates as files might work better in pre Docker solutions. With Docker, you have to mount separate storage or use a database. Since most rendering parameters already reside in a database, I find it easier to also put the templates there as to make all the data accompany each other. Otherwise you might have the problem of versioning and parameter values not matching the templates upon e.g. restore of a backup.